# How can I change the default shell for a specific workspace in VS Code? (Not globally)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to set a specific shell for only one workspace, which pops up when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>. But not globally for all workspaces.

For example, my default VS Code shell is the Windows Command Prompt. I have only one project in which I need Git Bash to be the default shell.

I tried creating a json setting file in the workspace's `.vscode/` directory but I don't know what setting to change there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a workspace settings.json (in the workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file), and in it, configure whichever of the following variables that you wish:

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": null,   // TODO: pick one
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": null,     // TODO: pick one
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": null, // TODO: pick one
```

You can edit what profiles are defined by editing the following settings:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": { ... },
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": { ... },
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": { ... },
```